# Angular: Show html page passing value

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a page that I use to show 3 differents html depending on where it is called.

In a page I have:

```
 openCreateAnagraphics(){
    this.router.navigate(["/anagraphics", {customerUpdate: true}]);
  }
```

So I'm navigate to anagraphics.

there I have in my anagraphics.page.ts:

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.handleParams();
}

handleParams() {
        let params = this.route.snapshot.params;
        console.log("this.route.snapshot", this.route.snapshot)
        console.log("params", params)
        this.customerUpdate = params.customerUpdate ? params.customerUpdate : false
        console.log("this.customerUpdate ", this.customerUpdate)    
    }
```

and in the anagraphics.page.html

```
<div *ngIf="....">
        <div>
            //this is showed if I come from another way
        </div>
</div>


<div *ngIf="customerUpdate">
        <div>
            HELLO // there is the problem 
        </div>
</div>
```

but I see only a white page and my url is

> http://localhost:4200/anagraphics;customerUpdate=true

I would to obtain that I if i click on the button that calls openCreateAnagraphics, I'll go in a page that show the html when customerUpdate = true.

EDIT 1:

In my app-routing.module.ts

```
  { path: 'anagraphics', loadChildren: () => import('./anagraphics/anagraphics.module').then(m => m.AnagraphicPageModule), canActivate: [AuthGuard], data: { configurator: true, customerUpdate: false } },
```

but in this way customerUpdate is always on false.

Comment: `http://localhost:4200/anagraphics;customerUpdate=true` is not a valid URL, seems you are trying to pass for query params, the URL should be: `http://localhost:4200/anagraphics?customerUpdate=true`

Comment: As above, I think some webservers support ';' as a replacement for '&' as a query param seperator, but not as a replacement for '?' to establish the list of params. Could just be a transcription error though, in which case you need to provide some details about how your app is using routing.

Comment: Yes it isn't a valid url, but I only pass a param and retrieve the url in this way..

Comment: I have edited my code adding app-router.module

Comment: Can you try to reproduce in StackBlitz? It looks fine for me. [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9ay48h?file=src/app/anagraphics/anagraphics.component.ts)

Answer (score 2):

My solution reference link: https://angular.io/api/router/RouterEvent

In your `.routing.module.ts` file add data like the below.

```
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  component: AlertsComponent,
  data: {
    // What data you want to pass add that here
  }
}]
```

Then get that value in your common component like below. (Like: app or nav component)

```
  constructor(public router: Router) {
    router.events.pipe(
       filter((e: Event): e is RouterEvent => e instanceof RouterEvent)
    ).subscribe((e: RouterEvent) => {
      // Get your route data here
    });
  }
```